# How to access all restaurants from my current Location using MapKit in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Hello Everyone,
                 I am developing an app which have to show all the restaurants from my current Location with pins. I have not used mapKit before. so please help me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance. I read all apps related to MapKit but unable to understand how to access / retrieve the google maps.

**Update**: 
I enable the pin in Map for my current location but unable to access the restaurants available near the current location, I tried by giving "

> http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=restaurants&output=xml

" - this link is not accessing restaurants. can any one help me to access the restaurants. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, using API of Google Map :
http://code.google.com/intl/vi-VN/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

Answer (score 1):

You will need your own database of restaurants, or query google directly and parse the results. MapKit only provides the ability to display a map and put pins on it. You must supply all data yourself.

If you're just looking for information on displaying the map, simply placing a MapView object in a view in Interface Builder will display the map, you then have to set the location and zoom levels to zero in on the area you want.

Comment: thanks for you reply. You have seen the AroundMe app, I think they have not use any database because you have to see the memory occupied by the app in device. can you suggest me How to ask query google directly to parse the result.